# Spring 4 MVC+Apache Tiles 3+JQuery

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, tiles

Is it possible from a jquery function call a controller method that it redirect some description tiles page?

For instance:
First, I have this description tiles page like this:

```
<definition name="IndexDefinitionTiles" extends="base.definition">
   <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/_index.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Second, I have a method controller that call the description tiles page like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/goingPage", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})    
public @ResponseBody String goingPage(HttpServletRequest request) {

    //This is a definition Tiles page.
    return "IndexDefinitionTiles";

}
```

Third, I have this JQuery function:

```
// Catch event on button.
$("#btnCallGoingMethod").click(function (evt) {
     //Here i wanna call the method /goingPage that redirect to IndexDefinitionTiles
});
```

Is it possible?

I take the opportunity to ask you whether this is possible to do by $.ajax, I'd wanna know how could it be.

Comment: Is it possible? Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of the js file put this

```
var serverContext = window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("/",2));
```

then in your function

```
// Catch event on button.
$("#btnCallGoingMethod").click(function (evt) {
   window.location.href = serverContext + "/goingPage";
});
```